# How to move my 4GB+ file from my computer to a VPS with only terminal access?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, vps

I have bought a VPS where I have terminal access via SSH. I have a zip file of the project I want to move to this VPS, sized about 4 GB+. However there seem to be no way upload this file to either Dropbox, Google Drive, Mega, etc. and download it via the terminal. How would I go about moving this file from my Arch Linux set-up to this Debian VPS?

Edit: I am using Google's VPC to host a VPS, meaning that the server is connected to SSH via a website SSH. I am not directly connecting to the VPS via my own terminal to the VPS terminal.

Comment: if you have ssh access, does `scp` work?

Comment: scp echoes "usage: scp ..." on both machines, yes! I will look into the documentation of scp now!

Comment: `scp file user@remote:`

Comment: I cannot connect to the VPS from my terminal because I need to enable guest-os which needs metadata I do not have in order to generate a key when I access it which I will use to create a key to upload to the server, which I cannot do because I need to add myself somewhere else first... their documentation for SSH access to their VPS's are a complete mess. I have 10 tabs open because every single step has a "Do this first!" which is another program I need, which always ends in "Install our gcloud" instead of "do this to fix it"

Comment: I also cannot connect to the VPS server via my own terminal because of the error "myusername@12.345.67.891: Permission denied (publickey)." but the public key is in "authorized keys" in .ssh on the VPS as well as the ssh key registry on the website :(

Comment: Please update your question to include the information. Putting it here in the comments means it can easily get missed. Make it easy for us to help you

Comment: Your previous comment is at odds with the first sentence in your question. Please edit your question to clarify which is correct, maybe deleting un-needed comments as you go

Comment: You can also use `nc` if you don't care about encryption/privacy

Comment: @roaima I have added it "I am not directly connecting to the VPS via my own terminal to the VPS terminal." Google sets up a browser based SSH and handles keys internally. I have no control or vision of this operation. It isn't really relevant either. Please do not have a cancerous stackexchange spirit you're oozing right now. Either change the attitude of "You need to be 10+ years sysadmin with crystal clear description and understanding of each aspect of everything" or leave.

Comment: Can you copy files from your computer to your account at Google Drive? And can you copy files from your account at Google Drive to this VPS? In that case, how big files can you upload to Google Drive? (I think the total size for free (as in free beer) accounts at Google Drive is 15 GB, but I don't know the maximum file size.)

Comment: I have uploaded files > 1 GB to my account at Google Drive. Maybe you can split the huge file, transfer the parts and merge them at the target. The command `split` can split the files, and `cat` can merge them.

Comment: @sudodus the issue is that there is no download link on google drive. There is a download button, but the VPS is terminal only.

Comment: It seems that your access to the VPS is very limited. We can only guess what you are able/allowed to do. For example: Can you install program packages into your VPS, or have you only a userID without privileges? Can you run only `ssh` or also some other networking tools, `sftp`, `nc` `wget` or some other file transfer tool and that way get files from the internet? Maybe you can get more information from the vendor, some person at the company that provides the VPS service to you.

Comment: Maybe you can get an account at SourceForge. You should be able to manage files via command line, for example via the git system. [There is no maximum quota limit, but an 'honor' system](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Disk%20Quotas/).

Comment: @sudodus I have mentioned the company I rent the VPS from. `wget` works. I can install apps via `apt-get install`. I do not think it is limited, just that I do not fully understand the VPS because it is badly build and people here seem to not read the post lol.

Comment: Maybe you can install some [tools to get graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398) including a light-weight web browser into the VPS system and that way get access via the download button at Google Drive. Otherwise, if you upload the file (maybe split into 5 chunks) at SourceForge, you should be able to get it with `wget` (and you had better use checksums too, to be sure that the file transfer is correct.

Comment: @sudodus the issue is that I do not ssh into the VPS, the browser sets up that for me. I cannot pass any extra arguments, such as -X. Also I cannot register at SourceForge because I get error "System Error [F37236]" on my phone, laptop, computer and ipad. Across 4 different browsers and 3 different networks.

Comment: Hahasajk please stop using the comments for extra information. I've already explained why

Comment: you have the scp command on the server, so you could just (temporarily?) open up ssh connection to your local machine and invoke `scp` on the remote system